# Why does 4 wire SPI read operation need me to read MISO line on every transmit operation?

Tags: stm32, spi

I wish to read a SPI slave device. Here's what I thought the procedure would be like :

**CS_LOW**

1. SPI_Write(slave_address)
2. SPI_Write(register)
3. SPI_Write(0x00)            //dummy byte
4. data = SPI_Read()

**CS_HIGH**

However, this doesn't work. To make it work, here's what I have to follow:

**CS_LOW**

1. SPI_Write(slave_address)
2. temp = SPI_Read()
3. SPI_Write(register)
4. temp = SPI_Read()
5. SPI_Write(0x00)               //dummy byte
6. data = SPI_Read()

**CS_HIGH**

Why do I have to read the data on MISO line even when I know there will be nothing desirable?

PS: The SPI Read() and Write() functions are just my own implementations, nothing particular to a single MCU.

Edit : As requested, I am providing some details on the MCUs.

I am using two MCUs - **STM32F303VCT** and **TI TIVA123GH6PM**. Both the MCUs require me to follow the said procedure.

Here's my implementation of SPI transmit & receive function on STM32

```
uint8_t SPI_rdwr(uint8_t data)
{
    
    *(__IO uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR = data;              //send data
    
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));                // wait till TX buffer is empty
    
    while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);                  // wait if SPI line is busy
    
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));               //wait till RX buffe is NOT empty                   

    return *(__IO uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;          //return data if data received on MISO line
    
}
```

Comment: It is just the nature of full-duplex data transmission.

Comment: Whether it works or not depends on the MCU and the SPI implementation it has and the code you wrote to use it. Would you disclose what MCU you are using to answer this?

Comment: It may be that SPI_Read is what clocks the READ data into the CPU ... thereby also clocking the WRITE data out to the peripheral. If so, omitting it won't work.

Comment: Or the SPI hardware has a read buffer that can receive e.g. one byte and will not update from the shift register unless read. We don't know unless @Luffy provides us with the exact MCU make/model and provides code to see what is wrong.

Comment: Since it's your own implementation, please tell us what the SPI_Read() function does

Comment: @Justme I have added some details as edit.

Comment: @user253751 I have added some details now. Please look into it. In my subroutine I have combined both transmit and receive procedures into one. I have a separate transmit function where I just 1.write to data register and 2.wait till TX buffer is empty. I use the transmit function when I just wish to write to a particular register on slave device.

Comment: Then my guess is: if the receive buffer is full you get a fault condition which stops SPI.

Comment: @Luffy But your spi_rdwr does not match what you asked first. It is up to the slave how it works, but your rdwr should work just fine for full-duplex operation, and in fact STM32 SPI requires you read the receive buffer or it won't update with the received data. The rdwr now transmits and receives one byte. And you don't mention with what slave you communicate with, so I can't tell you if the protocol is correct or not.

Comment: @Justme it's a MCP23S17 IO expander. Most slave devices require sending 3 bytes in a chip select cycle  is what I would imagine. The rdwr in the code just integrates both the SPI_Write and SPI_Receive functions I mentioned as an algorithm, since write is proceeded by a read anyway

Comment: @Luffy No you imagine wrong, any device is free to choose whatever protocol the designers chose. MCP23S17 is slightly weird. It requires write of opcode, register, and then write or read of data. There are no dummy bytes so the neither sequence you presented is correct.

Comment: @Luffy Justme is right. SPI is just a way to move bytes around. What those bytes mean, and logically who's the write and who's the reader is completely arbitrary, and full duplex operation is also possible and some devices may support it well while some others do a mediocre job.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does 4 wire SPI read operation need me to read MISO line on every transmit operation?

Because:

1. For performance reasons, the HAL implementers wrote SPI_Write without the "wait for transmit register empty" loop built in, but `SPI_Read` has such a loop. In that case, issuing writes without reads would overrun the buffer. Your implementation also wastes time in that loop - once you can read, you can write, too; or
2. The hardware abstraction library (HAL) you're using configures the silicon to work that way, when the silicon doesn't require it to be so,
3. and perhaps you're not configuring the HAL to do it the way you want, in case the HAL supported it (and necessarily also the silicon); or
4. perhaps you're not configuring the silicon to do the "right" thing when the silicon allows that; or
5. the silicon is designed to work that way and no other way.

I don't recall the details of SPI implementation on the chips you're using, but:

1. Some SPI implementations can have the receiver switched off, and thus reads won't be necessary since that function will be disabled.
2. SPI can be probably used with DMA, thus you won't care about the overhead of doing the reads too much.
3. Even if you do it in software, the reads may be cheap. Not using the HAL would probably help with that too, although be sure to compile the code in optimized release configuration, and audit the assembly to confirm that it doesn't do anything unnecessary. Even your hand-written code does unnecessary things.